# sdl2 не записывает данные в файл на android

Tags: android, linux, c, jni

функция SDL_RWwrite возвращает ноль, это значит что есть ошибка. как же сделать чтобы можно было записать данные?

```
static void write_language ( const char *name ) {
#ifdef __LINUX__
    FILE *fp = fopen ( "assets/languages/language", "w" );
    fwrite ( name, 1, strlen ( name ), fp );
    fclose ( fp );
#endif
#ifdef __ANDROID__

    SDL_RWops *io = SDL_RWFromFile ( "languages/language", "w" );
    if ( io ) {
        int len = strlen ( name );
        int length = SDL_RWwrite ( io, name, len, 1 );

        SDL_RWclose ( io );
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте путь относительно `SDL_AndroidGet{In|Ex}ternalStoragePath()`. Еще можно посмотреть, что записывается в `glGetError`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat неа, не выходит. а точно в glGetError записывается, это разве не opengl функция?

Comment: Пардон, `SDL_GetError` конечно.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat пишет "Cannot write to Android package filesystem"

Comment: Говорит, что файлы, которые вы упаковываются вместе с приложением - ридонли. А если указать путь относительно `SDL_AndroidGet{In|Ex}ternalStoragePath()`, тогда что пишет?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat вообще возвращает null для структуры.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat может это потому что приложение типа отладочного. может если отправить его в google play, то всё нормально будет? или может надо как то разрешение на запись получить?

Comment: Да ну, вряд ли. Как без этого приложение-то тестировать? Что, обе функции 0 возвращают? А если после них вызвать `SDL_GetError`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat о, а об этом я не подумал. ладно. завтра проверю и отпишусь.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я посмотрел что в таком случае пишет. `"java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xverizex.space_travels/files/languages/language"`

Comment: Может папку `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xverizex.space_travels/files/languages/` надо создать?

Comment: а как тогда работать с этим? например я все файлы поместил в assets. а в этом files нет ни одного файла. я думаю это не правильное место. или правильное?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, в этот файл записывается. наверное это то что нужно. спасибо.

Comment: Емнип, `assets` хранятся где-то в сжатом виде и разархивируются на лету (RWops-ом, поэтому через обычные функции работы с файлами их не достать), и поменять их из приложения нельзя.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat всё работает. спасибо.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я посмотрел код SDL_RWops, оказывается всё очень просто. они используют SDL_AndroidGetInternalStoragePath. то есть если бы я сразу посмотрел, то не нужно было бы переписывать по другому код. а то для линукса я использовал fgets, а в SDL_RW нет такой функции.

Comment: Хм, и что, простым `fopen`-ом на чтение получается открыть?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat неа. я пробывал несколько вариантов. в assets fopen не работает. если открывает internal, то вроде срабатывает. а assets там jni функций куча по работе с файлами.